# Why I got error "e: error: cannot access DataSource", if I use ViewModelFactory?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, android-paging

I'm trying to implement paged list in recycler view, using andoroid pagination library. I also use ViewModel class. But i getting a weird error

In my viewmodel, i have a property activeDataSource in which i want to hold the last datasource object(which created via DataSourceFactory), and call datasource method invalidate when i got notify from repository that list was updated.

But I get an error about the origin of which I have no clue:
e: error: cannot access DataSource

It is noteworthy that if i dont use my own ViewModelFactory to сreate new viewmodel object then i am not getting this error.

What causes this error?

My viewmodel class:

```
    class ArticleDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: NewsRepository
    ) : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {

    private var activeDataSource: DataSource<Int, Article>? = null

    val articlesLiveList: LiveData<PagedList<Article>>
        get() {
            val dataSourceFactory = ArticleDataSourceFactory(repository)

            val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build()

            Log.e("asd", "=== Create list live data ===")
            return LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, config)
                .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build()
        }

    fun onResetClick() {
        repository.onIvalidate()
    }

    fun setDataSource(data: DataSource<Int, Article>) {
        activeDataSource = data
    }
}
```

And default viewmodel factory:

```
 class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModelsMap: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = viewModelsMap[modelClass] ?: viewModelsMap.asIterable().firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        return try {
            creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my viewmodel module. It's also looks very default:

```
@NewsScope
@Module
interface NewsViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ArticleDetailsViewModel::class)
    fun testViewModel(viewModel: ArticleDetailsViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Comment: Where are you passing a reference to `DaggerViewModelFactory`?

Comment: I'm inject DaggerViewModelFactory in activity onCreate method. And using factory i create all viewmodel i need